# Can't hide property or filed of base class using new keyword

Tags: c#

We use a dll for some applications. App can't set all the properties of object of class type of that dll. dll itself only populate some of it fields.

Now, for special reason, I have to set some properties in one application. Normally, we don't extend the class of the dll. Here I am extending the class of dll and I am using "new" keyword to hide the base property. The intention is to set value in that property.

The base class is in another different namespace,

```
namespace AnotherAssembly
{
    public abstract class AbstructHead
    {
        public Int16 Int_toHide{ get; internal set; }
        public Int16 Int_noHide { get;  set; }
        public DateTime ReadTime { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

In the extended class, "new" keyword is used,

```
namespace TestingNew
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //AbstructHead ah = new AbstructHead();
            AbstructHead ah = new Assist();
            Assist ext = (Assist)ah;

            ext.Int_toHide = 20;
            ext.Int_noHide = 30;
            ext.ReadTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 18);


            DateTime readTime = ah.ReadTime;
        }
    }

    public class Assist : AbstructHead
    {
        new public Int32 Int_toHide{ get; set; }
        new public DateTime ReadTime { get; internal set; }

    }
}
```

Following is the screenshot of watch window,

[image: The watch window after execution of the code.]

You see, the I couldn't make it working. What is the problem here in the code. How can I populate data? "ah.ReadTime" gives me nothing.

```
DateTime readTime = ah.ReadTime;
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how `new` works. You can't replace the property in the base case by using `new`, you only hide it. So by setting `ReadTime` on `ext` you are only setting the `ReadTime` property on `Assist`, the base one is unaffected.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen? **new** simply indicates to the compiler that you wish to create a separate field or method while acknowledging the fact that a same-named field or method exists in the base class.

Comment: Don't forget that Int_toHide in the base class expects to return a short, but you extend it to int, so you're breaking the base class rule here.

Comment: @adelphus, The reason of using "new" is to set property or field of base class. "set" is not accessible as that is "internal". I can't change the dll code. But I need to set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic properties (the ones with just `get; set;`) generate a field for you when the code is compiled. So in the `Assist` class you aren't setting the value of the base class, you're just setting the value of a new field.

To make this work, you should implement the property yourself:

```
public class Assist : AbstructHead
{
    new public Int32 Int_toHide
    { 
        get { return base.Int_toHide; }
        set { base.Int_toHide = value; }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the property of the base class is `internal`, so this will only work if `Assist` is defined in the same assembly (or is mentioned in the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute).

And as a last resort you could choose to use reflection to set the base value.

**EDIT**

In response to the comments, here's how to access the property using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo property = typeof(AbstructHead).GetProperty("Int_toHide", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
if (property == null) 
{
    throw new ApplicationException("This version of AbstructHead does not have an Int_toHide property");
}

property.SetValue(this, value, null);
```

I don't know what your ultimate goal is, usually members are internal for a reason, and using reflection is usually not the best approach, so don't say I didn't warn you :/

Comment: Why would you recommend this? If all your property is doing is getting and setting the base field, **new** has no value here...?

Comment: They can't set `base.Int_toHide` because it's `internal`.

Comment: @adelphus its virtually changing the access modifiers of the property.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, the assembly of application code is different. This application can't use InternalsVisibleTo. Could you please describe how to use reflection for above mentioned case.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, You are right. There is a reason of using internal. Only one application will use those "set". However, I am using that dll for another application. For my application, those fields are read only. But I need to set the values for a specific task. The code I have posted here isn't the real code. I write this code to check why "new" isn't working in the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `new` won't replace a property in the base class, it only hides it. And it will only be seen if you have a reference that is typed to the derived class. For example, if you had this:

```
public class A
{
    private string _foo = "Foo";
    public string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return _foo;
        }

        private set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private string _foo = "Bar";
    public new string Foo
    {
        get
        {
            return _foo;
        }

        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And you do this:

```
A foo = new B();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Foo);     // Foo
```

Then this is going to call `Foo` on the class `A` because the type of `foo` is `A` (even though it contains an object of type `B`). To see the `new` property, you'd have to cast it:

```
B fooB = (B)foo;
Console.WriteLine(fooB.Foo);    // Bar
```

Now because the setter for `Foo` in `A` is marked as private, there is no way you can access it. Setting `Foo` on `B` will not change the value in `A`. Your `foo` object actually has two completely independent properties with the same name.

The only way you could get at the setter for `A` would be with reflection.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
So far I understand from your answer,
1. changing "new" property of extended class doesn't affect the Base property. If I point with the Base type, I will get unaffected state.

2. I will get changed value if I point with the extended class type.

Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance :)